# How to enter path to tls

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

In NodeJs I am able to connect to another server over TLS. What I am missing is how to enter `path`. I can enter `host` only.

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
   key  : fs.readFileSync('private.key'),
   cert : fs.readFileSync('public.cert')
};

var client = tls.connect(8000, 'localhost', options, function () {
   console.log(client.authorized ? 'Authorized' : 'Not authorized');
});
```

If I do `tls.connect(8000, 'localhost/my_path', ...)` it's resolving to `localhost/my_path:8000` which is wrong of course.

How to enter `path` elements?

Comment: i dont know. Im sorry

Comment: @FreezY it's okay

Comment: You probably want to use [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html).

Comment: @FreezY, don't worry. ;)

Comment: @robertklep in the end we used `https` and it worked. `tls.connect()` also has a parameter `path` but it's somehow not working. You maybe wish to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is "merely" a transport layer, on top of which other protocols can be implemented. One is HTTPS.

Since it looks like you want to make HTTPS requests, you'd want to use [`https.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) instead of using the `tls` module.

The `path` parameter of `tls.connect()` isn't analogous to the path of a URL, it's used to connect to a TLS server through a [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) (which is represented on the system by a file, which is what the `path` should point at).

Comment: We used `https.request()` but for `GET` it doesn't matter. Thx Robert.

Comment: @zatziky yeah, `https.get()` is just a convenient shortcut =D